# MySQL CLI not launching

Tags: mysql, sql

I just installed MySQL on my device but I am not able to open the Command Line Client for MySql. I think it launches and then instantly closes because I can see a flash of black. I have the MySQL service running as well. I have already tried searching various methods from the internet but I am not able to know what to do exactly. I have set the password already. Please someone help me.
I am using windows 10 x64 bit machine.

MySQL installation:

[image: MySQL Installation]

Services:

[image: MySQL service]

Trying to run MySQL on cmd (As Admin):

[image]

Comment: mysql.exe must posess in `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\"` or similar - what module do you start? use shortcut created by installer.. Also you must specify a lot of parameters - the posession of configuration file to be used at least..

Comment: @Akina I didn't understand the parameters statement but I am sure that mysql.exe is present in the mentioned directory and I am using the shortcut created by the installer, but it's not working. I think it has something to do with the root password because I even tried to start MySQL with cmd but it says access denied.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set environment variable path to the executable file location.

control panel ->
Edit environment variables ->
environment variables button at the bottom of the popup

The top window is for user specific variables, the bottom window is universal. choose which one you need.

click on the "Path" key select edit and navigate to the MySql.exe file (right click on the MySql Command Line Client shortcut and select open file location.)